# How to remove the Time part of a Date in a Linq Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I tried to remove the Time part of a Date from a Linq query to no avail. I used the **`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`** but it didn't work. Here is the my code

```
    var Cycle1 = 
        ((from sbm in context.SBMs 
         where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID 
         select new Cycle { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sbm.CrewSite.Crew.TodayDate) }
        ).OrderBy(x => x.Date).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()).Equals(null)
        ? (DateTime?)null 
        : ((from sbm in context.SBMs 
          where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID 
          select new Cycle { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sbm.CrewSite.Crew.TodayDate) }
          ).OrderBy(x => x.Date).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()).Date
```

Can someone help me see what i did wrong ?

Comment: `it didn't work`: What did you get error?

Comment: well I didn't get any error the function did not truncate the time

Comment: `did not truncate the time` You mean the value that you get return keep time part?

Comment: did you try `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(sbm.CrewSite.Crew.TodayDate)` ?

Comment: Yes. The Time part was kept

Comment: I tried EntityFunctions.TruncateTime but I received a  notification that it is deprecated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205181/discussion-between-anonymous-and-j-raoul-feze).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see, your value has been removed time part.

All you need to do is format the Date in `ListView`

Your case looks like this

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle1", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle1Label" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you already get the answer, however I see, you calling db query two times.. this has significant impact, possible for you to change above code like this

```
var cycleObj = ((from sbm in context.SBMs 
          where sbm.CrewSite.SiteID == site.SiteID 
          select new Cycle { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sbm.CrewSite.Crew.TodayDate) }
          ).OrderBy(x => x.Date).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()); 

var Cycle1 = cycleObj == null? (Date?)cycleObj.Date : (Date?) null;
```